# Need regex to add spaces in long words but ignore HTML tags and attributes

Tags: php, regex, split

I need to add spaces in words within product description at a user supplied positon (we'll say 25 for example) to allow proper wrapping. I know CSS tricks can be used but that's not what I'm loooking for.

So far I can do this using this syntax but the problem I'm having is that it's splitting stuff it shouldn't be splitting such as URLs in HTML tag attributes.

```
    $string = 'longwordlongwordlongword <a href="http://www.somelongdomainname.com/and-a-long-sub-directoty_name" class="some_long_class_name_here">someanchortext and title here</a>';

    $spacer = 20;

    $newtext = preg_replace('/([^\s]{' . $spacer . '})(?=[^\s])/m', '$1 ', $newtext);
```

The result is this....

```
    longwordlongwordlong word <a href="http://www.som elongdomainname.com/ and-a-long-sub-direc toty_name" class="some_long_cla ss_name_here">somean chortext and title here</a>
```

I need to somehow tell the regex to split everything EXCEPT HTML tags and attributes.

Comment: Do you only need to replace for the first `<a>`? Is there only one tag, namely `<a>` inside string always?

Comment: Do not use regex for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: You should do that programmatically. `Regex` is not capable of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure that you'll never have angle brackets (`<>`) inside attribute values or comments of your HTML file, then you could try this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/(        # Match and capture...
     [^\s<>]   # anything except whitespace and angle brackets
     {20}      # 20 times.
    )          # End of capturing group.
    (?!        # Assert that it\'s impossible to match the following:
     [^<>]*    # any number of characters except angle brackets
     >         # followed by a closing bracket.
    )          # End of lookahead assertion.
    /x', 
    '\1 ', $subject);
```

The idea here is to match a 20-character non-space-string only if the next angle bracket in the text isn't a closing bracket (which would mean that that string is inside a tag). Obviously this breaks if angle brackets could occur elsewhere.

You might also want to use `\w` instead of `[^\s<>]`, so you really only match alphanumeric strings (if that's what you want).